# Is it possible to create more then 500 subsite in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Is It possible to create more then 500 site in WordPress ? WordPress create new tables for each subsite so it will increase database load.

If it's possible it's effect on site performance?

Anyone would you please give proper Idea or solution how to manage 500 subsite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly effect overloading the MySQL database.

The first-level of “defense” on overloading the database would be to use the MySQL Query Cache.

The Query Cache is a nifty little feature in MySQL, where it stores — in a dedicated are within main memory — any results of a query for a table which has not recently changes.

Check out the following article:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/scaling-wordpress-wpmu-buddypress-like-edublogs/